# With openpyxl how can I find out how many cells are merged in .xlsx

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have sheet where the "heading" are in merged cells and the value is in the cells under the "heading", see example.

How can I count how many cells the heading spans? I need this to know where to start and stop reading the cells that belong to the "heading".

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  Heading1 | Heading2  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Do the cells in the header row have any sort of a "span" attribute?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by span attribute. I think their just manually merged.

Comment: There must be something in the Excel file that indicates that a header cell spans more than one cell of the row. Print a `dir()` of the cell object that openpyxl provides and see what its attributes are.

Comment: How do I print a dir()? like sheet.cell().dir() ?

Comment: Probably something like `dir(sheet.cell())`

Comment: There is no span attribute. Merged cells are kept as `A1:E2` ranges in Excel so client code has to implement it's own spanning calculation.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a function in VBA in Excel, like below

```
Public Function COLUMNSINMERGED(r As Excel.Range)

If r.MergeCells Then
    COLUMNSINMERGED=r.MergeArea.Columns.Count
    Debug.Print r.MergeArea.Address, "Cols : " & r.MergeArea.Columns.Count, "Rows : " & r.MergeArea.Rows.Count
else
   COLUMNSINMERGED=r.cells.count      
End If

End Function
```

Comment: The question is specifically about openpyxl.

Comment: The question is "How can I find out how many cells are merged in .xlsx" and you have an Excel tag, bit misleading then, not mentioning python except in a tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the **convertLetterToColumnNum** function from [Excel Column Number to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633017/excel-column-number-to-text)

```
#calculates the span given a merged cell
#first checks to see if cell is merged and then calculates the span
def calculateSpan(sheet, cell):
    idx = cell.coordinate
    for range_ in sheet.merged_cell_ranges:
        merged_cells = list(openpyxl.utils.rows_from_range(range_))
        for row in merged_cells:
            if idx in row:
                # If this is a merged cell
                first_col=convertLetterToColumnNum(str(merged_cells[0][0][0]))
                second_col = convertLetterToColumnNum(str(merged_cells[0][1][0]))
                span=abs(second_col-first_col)+1 #remove +1 if you want to count from zero
                return span

#usage
print(calculateSpan(mysheet,mysheet['D11']))
```

The rest is a modified version of [How do i get value present in a merged cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562366/how-do-i-get-value-present-in-a-merged-cell)