# openpyxl: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only error

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I was trying to copy data from one excel sheet to another using openpyxl but I am getting ('MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only) error. It is working fine when I am copying data from datasheets which doesn't contain merged cells.How can I copy data from sheet having merged cells?

Heres my code:

```
{for r in range(1,mr):
    for c in range(1,mc):
        ds3.cell(r,c).value=dbs1_3.cell(r,c).value}
```

Error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 for r in range(1,mr):
>         2     for c in range(1,mc):
>   ----> 3         ds3.cell(r,c).value=dbs1_3.cell(r,c).value
>         4
>
> AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562366/how-do-i-get-value-present-in-a-merged-cell